# Как сделать sql запрос такого вида, подобно сводной итоговой суммы в рамках одной таблицы?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть такая таблица в БД содержащая помесячную доходность в процентах

```
create table profits_month
(
    column_1    integer          not null,
    year        varchar          not null,
    month       varchar          not null,
    profit_loss double precision not null
);
```

Тестовые данные:

```
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (1, '2021', 'april', 2);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (2, '2021', 'may', 6);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (3, '2021', 'june', 1);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (4, '2021', 'july', 7);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (5, '2021', 'august', 0);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (6, '2021', 'semptember', -2);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (7, '2021', 'october', 15);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (8, '2021', 'november', 7);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (9, '2021', 'december', -1);
INSERT INTO public.profits_month (column_1, year, month, profit_loss) VALUES (10, '2022', 'january', 5);
```

- Вопрос как сделать sql-запрос, чтобы результат итоговый был такого вида: 
  условно результат за последний месяц, три месяца и т.е

| month_count | summa_itogo |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 40 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 1 | 5 |

Comment: Ну нужно выучить функции агрегации типа SUM, COUNT и GROUP BY и применить их практике

Comment: тут скорее проблема как сделать в рамках одной таблицы, по одной строке то понятно, но как сделать типо сводную таблицу / тут сложность возникает

Comment: Обычное условное агрегирование. `SUM(CASE WHEN month BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS sum_for_3_months`.

Comment: о что то интересное ) уже , условия THEN value ELSE ранее не знал Спасибо за наводку ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не совсем ясна, 10 месяцев из примера означают именно 10 месяцев или максимум данных, которые есть в базе. Так же две колонки год и название месяца не позволяют с ними работать по человечески (лучше держать поле с датой, 1е число нужного месяца и года). Поэтому опираться приходиться на колонку column_1 и надеяться, что она возрастает.

При данных оговорках задача должна решаться так:

```
select month_count, summa_itogo
  from (
    select count(1) over(order by column_1 desc) as month_count,
           sum(profit_loss) over(order by column_1 desc) as summa_itogo,
           count(1) over() all_count
      from profits_month
  ) x
  where month_count in(1, 3, all_count)
  order by month_count desc
```

С помощью [оконных функций](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/tutorial-window) выбираем количество месяцев и сумму нарастающим итогом. А так же общее количество строк. Во внешнем запросе оставляем от полученного результата только записи 1, 3 и "за все время".

Comment: Вы просто супер cool ---> !!!